# How to Run Identity Server 4 Source Code on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, identityserver4

I am new to Identity Server 4 and want to explore its features. So I started first by running the Source Code on Ubuntu( as it is .Net Core project). I have checked out to tag 3.1.1, installed the required SDK and able to build the project as per the given directions in the Readme.md file on [github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/3.1.1). But when I am trying to Run the IdentityServer4.dll specified in the path IdentityServer4/src/IdentityServer4/src/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/IdentityServer4.dll, I am getting an Error as follows:

*Unhandled exception. System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'IdentityServer4.Storage, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***********'.
Aborted (core dumped)*

Can Anyone please tell me am I doing anything in the wrong direction.

Comment: After verifying the Package Structure of IdentityServer4 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/3.1.1) I have found one more IdentityServer4.dll on the path IdentityServer4/src/IdentityServer4/src/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/IdentityServer4.dll. If I run dotnet command in this path I am getting the following exception. Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (IdentityServer4.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'IdentityModel', version: '4.1.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to ASP.NET core I recommend you to firstly create a normal HelloWorld application in ASP.NET core and deploy that to ubuntu server but for that you need to install several things on your ubuntu servers to run a dotnet core application and that are as belows:-

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-3.0
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.0
```

After all that you have to run your dll which is run like this:

```
dotnet [filename].dll
```

NOTE:- Please Don't forget to reload your nginx after your changes as it also require some kind of changes.

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.
I had already installed the required SDK i.e. 3.1.100 in my system. Still again I have followed your commands, still, the issue persists.

Comment: What issue you are facing please tell me when you run your application.

Comment: I am trying to Run the IdentityServer4 Source code. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/3.1.1 I have built the code but when I am running the dll I am getting the above mentioned error.